# Why doesn't my free dyno hours decrease? (Picture included)

Tags: heroku

My question is "**why my free dyno hours are not decreasing**".

As the image below shows, I am using heroku to take cryptocurrencies price data from Binance via API. My python codes to use Binance is uploaded on github and deployed to heroku. The price data imported is sent to telegram, whose chatbot sends me messages.

Does anyone know why my free dyno hours are not decreasing?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My free dyno hour turns out to decrease, but it just takes time to get reflected on the dashboard.